# classify `SpatRaster` map using attributes not values

Tags: r, gis, spatial, r-raster, terra

I would like to classify a raster map (`SpatRaster`) based on the attribute table attached to it, not the cell values.

Here is a reprex from the help of the `terra::activeCat()` function:

```
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE) + 10
d <- data.frame(id=11:13, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"), letters=letters[1:3], value=10:12)
levels(r) <- d
cats(r)

# [[1]]
# id  cover letters value
# 11 forest       a    10
# 12  water       b    11
# 13  urban       c    12
```

I would like to change cells with `urban` class (`cover == "urban"`) into `NA`.

```
# this does not work
activeCat(r) <- 2
classify(r, cbind("urban", NA))
```

```
# this works but using the cell value
classify(r, cbind(13, NA))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subst`

Example data

```
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE) + 10
d <- data.frame(id=11:13, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"), letters=letters[1:3], value=10:12)
levels(r) <- d
```

Solution

```
s <- subst(r, "urban", NA)
```

Although it is a bit odd to set a label to NA. So I would do this instead

```
ss <- subst(r, 13, NA, raw=TRUE)
```

Or the equivalent with `classify` that you show.

for more complex cases, you can remove the categories and then reset them later

```
cts <- cats(r)
levels(r) <- NULL
# do something with r
# 
levels(r) = cts
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. In my data, it is challenging for me to know the value I want to replace. Is it possible to extract attributes along with the data using e.g. `as.data.frame()`?

In this file [https://wetransfer.com/downloads/afceeaad5f2138a834dc8dfa23a8b32d20230607181034/b65973 ] for cropped Corine LC data, the value 128 represents NA but I can not see that value in the `cats()` output.

How can I replace cells with values of `CODE_18 == 999`, for example, with NA, without knowing the actual values of the cells. I need to enforce these cells to read as NA. Thanks.

Comment: See my expanded answer. You can remove the levels first.